# NSPredicate on an array of PFUsers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array of `PFUsers` by using the predicate below, but this is not working. The NSLog gives shows empty arrays every time I type a character in the UISearchBar. Is there something I'm not understanding about how NSPredicate works?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{   
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username contains %@",searchText];


    _searchResults = [[_messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"_searchResults: %@",_searchResults);
}
```

My array of PFUser Objects

```
2014-01-29 22:46:19.667 My-App[28fg8:70c] messages: (
    "<PFUser:X5819CS5:(null)> {\n    email = \"useremail@gmail.com\";\n    emailVerified = 0;\n    username = JohnSmith10;\n}"
)
```

Result from typing "De" into the search bar

```
predicate: username CONTAINS[c] "De"
2014-01-30 00:35:25.727 My-app[34fg8:10c] searchtext: De
```

Comment: try using `contains[c] %@`

Comment: @Akhilrajtr still producing an empty searchResult

Comment: Check your `searchText` in your predicate. Just NSLog your predicate..

Comment: @Anusha logged, edited above

Comment: you only have one `PFUser` named `JohnSmith10` and your search string is `De`.

Comment: @GoGreen I changed the names so that they aren't names of my actual users.